# Does Deadlock need two thread waiting for each other resources?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I have this program where two threads waits for same lock Stock Object and causes program to hang. But Thread1 is NOT waiing for the lock Thread2 and vice versa. What is this situation called if this is not a Deadlock?

```
public class DeadlockSimulator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stock st = new Stock();
        Runnable p1 = new Producer(st);
        Runnable c1 = new Consumer(st);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(c1);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

public class Producer implements Runnable{
    private final Stock st;
    public Producer(Stock st) {
        this.st=st;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            while(true)
                st.addStock(3);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Stock {
    private int qoh; 
    public Stock() {
    }

    public synchronized int getStock(int required) throws InterruptedException
    {
        int take=0;
        if(qoh> required)
        {
            qoh=qoh-required;
            take=required;
            //notify();
        }
        else
        {
            wait();
        }
        return take;
    }
    public synchronized void addStock(int stocks) throws InterruptedException
    {
        if(qoh >7)
        {
            wait();
        }
        else
        {
            qoh=qoh+stocks;
            System.out.println("Current Stock"+ qoh);
        //  notify();
        }
    }
    public int getorderLevel()
    {
        return this.qoh;
    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private final Stock st;
    public Consumer(Stock st) {
        this.st = st;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                int got = st.getStock(5);
                System.out.println("Got =" + got);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an example of two threads waiting on a *single* resource, the `Stock.` Not a deadlock.

Comment: The program hangs because you have an infinite loop in run()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: this is not an example of deadlock.
It is an example of [synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html), which is a form of [concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control).
In Java, producer/consumer problems are often solved by using a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).